# what3words APIv2 UI wrapper with Google Maps

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Our website is trying to integrate with both Google Maps and [What3words](https://map.what3words.com/). I need to build an UI display a map with.

1. A marker on the map, and a search box.
2. When dragging marker, can retrieve the corresponding 3 words based on its geo coordinate.
3. When typing into the searchbox, can retrieve the three word based on auto complete result from Google.
4. Actually it should look like below picture.

[image: what3words]

What I have archived so far is getting the source code from [What3words-map-marker](https://github.com/Logic-gate/What3words-map-marker) that support What3words API v1 already. But now all the API from What3words has migrated to API v2.

May I check If there are any release from What3words that support wrapper it with Google Maps and API v2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I follow your question exactly but my company also has just recently implemented something might be the same with your requirement.

Please check [this Github page](https://trungk18.github.io/what3words-api-v2-google-map-marker/) for more detail. Image as below.

[image]